# Postfix to Infix in Python

Tags: python, stack, runtime, analysis, postfix-mta

I got a python challenge to complete. The program is to take as input the formula in one line, and the number of operations per second in addition to the time constraint in the next line.

Here is a direct explanation:

f(n) = n^3 + 3n^2 + 2n + 1

therefore in postfix this would be:

n 3 ^ 3 n 2 ^ * + 2 n * + 1 +

So the input would be:

```
n 3 ^ 3 n 2 ^ * + 2 n * + 1 +
100 5
```

the first line is the formula in postfix form
the 100 in the second line represents the speed (100 operations second)
and the 5 in the second line represents the time constraint in seconds, therefore the function can only perform a total of 500 operations.

What I would like to know is:

1. How would I convert from postfix to infix with no multiplications symbols?

OR

2. How could I solve the problem using the postfix form as it is?

With the latter would having a lower runtime

Here is some sample input and output that has been provided with the problem:

Sample Input:

```
n 3 ^ 3 n 2 ^ * + 2 n * + 1 +
100 5
```

Sample Output:

```
6
```

Here is what I have so far. It is just the postfixToInfix function that needs tweaking:

## !/bin/python3

```
import os
import sys

OPERATORS = ['+', '-', '*', '/', '^'] 

def postfixToInfix(formula, stack, cnt):
    if cnt == len(formula):
        return ''.join(str(e) for e in stack)
    if formula[cnt] != " ":  
        
        if(formula[cnt] in OPERATORS):
            for i in range(len(stack)-1, 0, -1):
                if stack[i] == "x":
                    stack[i] = formula[cnt]
        else:
            stack.append(formula[cnt])
            
        if formula[cnt] not in OPERATORS:
            stack.append("x")
    cnt += 1
    return postfixToInfix(formula, stack, cnt)
   

if __name__ == '__main__':
    exp = input()
    ct = input().split()
    c = int(ct[0])
    t = int(ct[1])    
    
    n = 0
    while True:
        if eval(postfixToInfix(exp, [], 0).replace("n",n)) > c*t:
            print(n-1)
            break
        n += 1
```